# How can I preload resources for many activities in android?

Tags: android, performance, resources

I have an application with several activities and a lot of image resources. I would like to be able to load these resources during the splash screen. I already have a splash screen, only currently it's just on a timer. I have read tutorials on how to pre-load for ONE activity, but that means when changing between activities there will be further loading.
The main steps in my application are like this:

Splash screen -> activity 1 -> activity 2 -> activity 3 -> activity 4

Activities 2 and 3 can return results back. I would like during the splash screen to load all the images I need in activity 1,2,3,4. It should fit in memory fine, but currently causes a delay when opening.

I believe I should use a singleton for this, load it up during my splash screen, then call to the splash screen to move on to activity 1.

When googling though, I can't find much on exactly how to do this.

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

Comment: Yeah, i've looked into Async Task a bit, and handlers, I can use that to load the resources whilst showing the splash screen. It's just knowing exactly how to create a singleton ( if I need it ), and how to load up and store the images in there to be able to get them from other activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton pattern is quite simple

```
public class Singleton{

    //variables
    private Bitmap asset;
    //getter method for asset
    public Bitmap getAsset(){
        return asset;
    }

    //Singleton Instance
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    //a private constructor
    private Singleton(){}

    //To get the singleton instance
    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(singleton == null){
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //some way of asynchronously loading assets - threads or AsyncTask
    public void loadAssets(){
        //do something to load assets asynchronously
    }
}
```

To use it is just

```
Singleton.getInstance().loadAssets();
```

and that's about it, create some getters for your assets and retrieve them like so

```
Singleton.getInstance().getAsset();
```

Comment: +1, Little update to ensure singleton work fine: public synchronized Singleton getInstance()

Comment: Should the getInstance method be static?

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance()?

If not, I get an error saying it should be...
Thanks

Comment: yeah, sorry, getInstance() should be static

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help. Sorry for the sub-question, i'm using this now, and i'm not able to save the bitmaps from res. I'm trying to use BitmapFactory.DecoreResource to decode, is this the correct thing to be doing? This is to store in this singleton, to pass to the activity in onCreate rather than having the activity decode images in onCreate

Comment: yes that's pretty much the idea. On a side note: you have to be careful of the Android lifecycle, if the app is put in the background there's the possibility that it might be killed and all your assets will be gone when the user returns to the app, which is going to result in null pointers. You should probably try to only load what you need just before you need it, you should look into the 'Lazy Loading' pattern too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend implementing a content provider, or your own disk caching mechanism instead of using the Singleton approach for these reasons:

- Using a static collection means you're keeping a reference for all the bitmaps during the whole application life cycle, this occupies more memory as you're referencing all the images even those the user is not interacting with at a moment.
- You'll have to maintain the synchronization of your static collection to avoid read/write interleave.
  -if your app is killed by the system to reclaim memory, and the user resumes interacting with the app, there will be a chance that your static collection get re initialized, so it will be empty and you need to load the references to your bitmaps again. This adds complexity to your application and introduces potential bugs.